# Label points the right way in a ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I need desperately your help. I have the following code. My problem is that there is an *error* (you see it in the picture) and I can't find. Then Mathematica gives me for the **global Min** two wrong points. The real point would be {-2.5,0} and not {1.5,1.5},{1.5,-1.5}. In addition I want subdivide the other points in **local Max** and **local Min**. I don't know how it's done. In addition it would be great, if the **label** of the points would appear in a better way (better fitted,....I don't know how it is called. But the label the way it is right now is a bit confusing and ugly).

`pts = {{1.5, 1.5}, {1.5, -1.5}, {2.5, 0}, {2.5, 1.94}, {2.5, -1.94}, {-2.5, 0}, {2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {2, -2}, {-2, -2}, {2.5, 2}, {-2.5, 2}, {-2.5, -2}, {2.5, -2}};
f[x_, y_] = y^4 - 3 x y^2 + x^3;`

```
f[x, y] == f[x, -y]
```

> True

`FindMaximum[{f[x, y], -2.5 <= x <= 2.5, -2 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}] // Rationalize[#, 10^-7] &`

> {32, {x -> -2, y -> 2}}

```
maxPts = {{x, y}, {x, -y}} /. %[[-1]]
```

> {{-2, 2}, {-2, -2}}

`FindMinimum[{f[x, y], -5/2 <= x <= 5/2, -2 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 50] // N`

> {-1.6875, {x -> 1.5, y -> -1.5}}

`minPts = {{x, y}, {x, -y}} /. %[[-1]]`

> {{1.5, -1.5}, {1.5, 1.5}}

`Solve[{D[f[x, y], x] == 0, D[f[x, y], y] == 0, -2.5 <= x <= 2.5, -2 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}] // Union // Quiet`

> {{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 1.5, y -> -1.5}, {x -> 1.5, y -> 1.5}}

`saddlePts = {{x, y}} /. %[[1]]`

> {{0, 0}}

`otherPts = Complement[pts, maxPts, minPts, saddlePts];`

`n = 1;
Legended[ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Contours -> {Automatic, 50}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thick], Frame -> False, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], ContourShading -> None, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Magenta, Bold], 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.015], Darker[Green], Point[otherPts], 
    Text[Style[ToString[f @@ #], Bold, Darker[Green], 
        Background -> Yellow], #, {0, (-1)^(n++) 1.5}] & /@ otherPts, 
    Red, Point[maxPts], 
    Text[Style[ToString[f @@ #], Bold, Red, 
        Background -> Yellow], #, {0, (-1)^(n++) 1.5}] & /@ maxPts, 
    Orange, Point[minPts], 
    Text[Style[ToString[f @@ #], Bold, Orange, 
        Background -> Yellow], #, {0, (-1)^(n++) 1.5}] & /@ minPts, 
    Darker[Blue], Point[saddlePts], 
    Text[Style[ToString[f @@ #], Bold, Darker[Blue], 
        Background -> Yellow], #, {0, (-1)^(n++) 1.5}] & /@ 
     saddlePts}], 
 PointLegend[{Red, Darker[Green], Darker[Blue], Orange, 
   Lighter[Green]}, {"global Max", "local Max", "Saddle", 
   " global Min", "local Min"}]]`

[image]

The legend is shown in Mathematica. I didn't know how to copy it as well.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you feel is a more aesthetically pleasing style of labelling points?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by sub-divide the local minima/maxima ?

Comment: I have for example 10 points. 1 is the global Max, 1 the global Min, 5 are local Min and 3 are local Max

Comment: more aestetically would be no yellow background is needed as the values are readable without it. They are simply displayed in a "perfect" place.

Comment: If you do not want the yellow backgrounds on your labels, just delete the, `Background -> Yellow` statements from your `ContourPlot` command.

Comment: I know, but then some points are unreadable. The position of the label needs to be better

Comment: You can control the font size of the label in the `Style` directive, `Style[ToString[f @@ #], Bold, Orange, 16]` to make it more readable. You have control over where the label is placed by specifying its x,y coordinates. maybe you want to add offsets to some of your labels to bring them in line with your aesthetics ?

Comment: I"m not sure I've understood what you mean by sub-divide, you have the various points assigned to different symbols in your code, in what context do you want to dived them ?

Comment: My points shall be divided into global Max, global Min, local Max, local Min and saddle points.

Comment: Haven't you done that by assigning them to symbols , maxPts, saddlePts etc ... ? Or perhaps you mean something different ?

Comment: not all points. I did it only with the global Max/Min and saddlepoints

Comment: and you want to do something different with the local versions ?

Comment: yes. They shall be displayed in a different color in the plot

Comment: You've displayed the saddle, max and  min points in different colours, can't you use  the same method for the local max and local min ?

Answer (score 2):

`FindMinimum` returns local minima.

You need `Minimize` which will return the global minimum.

```
Minimize[{f[x, y], -5/2 <= x <= 5/2, -2 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50] // N
```

> > {-15.625, {x -> -2.5, y -> 0.}}

Comment: This is _just a part_ of my question